# Lookig for a better/stronger sentence

Tags: phrases, american-english, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Could anybody let me know a stronger/improved sentence for the one shown below:

One of my interest is in applying machine learning to real world problems

Comment: Maybe: One of my primary/main [research] interests involves the possible ways to integrate machine learning [systems?] to real-world  situations. I guess, though, this has to be (slightly) formal.

Comment: What do you mean by stronger? Are you wishing to say that this is more than just an interest?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that interests me is exploring how machine learning can be applied to real world problems.

Comment: Actually, it does provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could phrase it in a way such as this:

I am interested in the way in which machine learning can be applied to real world problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way to strengthen a sentence is to **remove unnecessary words**. The message comes through more clearly if the sentence is short and to the point. Another way is to make the subject **more active**.

Thus, you could write, "I am interested in applying machine learning to real world problems."

Comment: Of course, whether this is the _best_ sentence depends on context. If the asker could provide more information on their goals (whether they are trying to list interests, contrast interests, lead into a more in-depth conversation of machine learning, etc.), I might be able to come up with a more specific answer.